# C# Odata v4 open type raw values

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata

I have a simple open type that contains dynamic properties:

```
public class Person {
    [Key]
    public string Uid { get; set; }     
    public IDictionary<string, object> DynamicProperties { get; set; }
}
```

In my controller, I fill these properties like this:

```
public IHttpActionResult Get([FromODataUri] string key) {
    Person person;
    // ...
    person.DynamicProperties.Add("foo", "foo_value");
    person.DynamicProperties.Add("bar", "bar_value");
    // ...
    return this.Ok(person);
}
```

I can figure how to request individually these properties - with an URL like ~/Person('uid')/foo - thanks to their keys and this method:

```
public IHttpActionResult GetDynamicProperty([FromODataUri] string key, [FromODataUri] string dynamicProperty) {
    Person person;
    // ...
    // (string) for the example
    return this.Ok((string)person.DynamicProperties[dynamicProperty]);
}
```

Result is like that:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "http://myServer/$metadata#Person('uid')/foo",
    "value": "foo_value"
}
```

But I can't figure how to get the raw value of these properties, with an URL like ~/Person('uid')/foo/$value

If I try it, the result is this one:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "",
        "message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://myServer/Person('uid')/foo/$value'.",
        "innererror": {
            "message": "No routing convention was found to select an action for the OData path with template '~/entityset/key/dynamicproperty/$value'.",
            "type": "",
            "stacktrace": ""
        }
    }
}
```

How I should route to have access to these raw values? Or is there a method or something else that could handle it?

-- Edit after [Sam Xu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46858298/7445285)'s answer

Thanks for your example, it works like a charm. I've followed your samples for points 1 and 2. For the point 3, if it can help someone, this is the adapted version for a classic Web API's Register method:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config) {
    // Custom routing for dynamic attributes raw values
    var routings = ODataRoutingConventions.CreateDefault();
    routings.Insert(0, new DynamicRawValueRoutingConvention());
    // Our model
    ODataModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
    builder.EntitySet<Person>("Person");
    // ...
    // Old way
    //config.MapODataServiceRoute(
    //    routeName: "myDefaultRouteName",
    //    routePrefix: null,
    //    model: builder.GetEdmModel()
    //);
    // New way with Sam's samples
    config.MapODataServiceRoute(
        "myDefaultRouteName",
        null,
        configureAction =>
        configureAction.AddService(ServiceLifetime.Singleton, sp => builder.GetEdmModel()).AddService<IEnumerable<IODataRoutingConvention>>(ServiceLifetime.Singleton, sp => routings)
    );
    var formatters = ODataMediaTypeFormatters.Create();
    foreach (var oDataMediaTypeFormatter in formatters) {
        oDataMediaTypeFormatter.MediaTypeMappings.Insert(0, new ODataDynamicValueMediaTypeMapping());
    }
    config.Formatters.InsertRange(0, formatters);
}
```

Comment: Would `~/Person('uid')?$select=foo` be sufficient?

Comment: Unfortunately no, because excepted if it could not be technically possible yet (I can't answer this), the clients expect the "classic" syntax that works with non dynamic attributes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Max Xapi

OData hasn't the built-in logic to support `$value` for dynamic property.

However, you can have workaround by yourself to accomplish it.

It's simple and only several steps:

1. create your own routing convention.
2. create the dynamic property value mapping
3. insert the routing convention and dynamic property value mapping into configuration.

I created a sample that you can refer to, see the commit [here](https://github.com/xuzhg/WebApiSample/commit/e42ab40dddd21e5da314f732abf73327be52eb1c). Please let me know any further problem and hope it can help.

Regards,

-Sam